# How to print the permutation of {s,u,v,a,t} with LaTeX?

Tags: programming

I want to use LaTeX to print the permutation of a set `{s,u,v,a,t}`. The output looks like the following.

```
suvat
suvta
suavt
suatv
...
```

There are 120 rows in total that must be generated on the fly.

How to do this with LaTeX?

### MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
.
\end{document}
```

Comment: @Papiro: don't give up with your dream, keep on sleeping! :-)

Comment: Give me time to decide the accepted answer based on 2 items: (1) portability and (2) readability.

Comment: @Bugbusters Do you really have to make such remarks about the code under each answer?

Comment: I think the focus on "portability" is misguided.  If you mistrust the machines you'll be TeXing this document on, then pre-generate the list of permutations and just `\input` it!  In fact, TeX it in advance, where you control the environment.  If you can't, write yourself a little program in some compiled language and carry it around with the document.  I mean, I recently was generating numerical solutions to nonlinear ODEs using an external tool; if you were doing that, would you want to do it in TeX?  It's possible (with pgf, say), but much harder.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Here's a better version, with lots of comments!  Incidentally, the method of generating all permutations is based on the [Knuth shuffle](http://tex.blogoverflow.com/2011/08/do-the-knuth-shuffle/).

The latest version of the code avoids nested loops and the separator is a `\par` token every now and again to avoid building too large boxes (see discussion in comments).  I ran it with `abcdefghij` and it worked, although the resulting document was 13746 pages long.

```
\documentclass{article}
%\url{http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/112975/86}
\usepackage{expl3}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\tl_new:N \l__perm_all_tl
\int_new:N \l__perm_int
\int_new:N \l__perm_len_int

% Print the permutations of #2 with prefix #1
\cs_new_nopar:Npn \generate_perms:nn #1#2
{
  % We need to recursively call this function to build up the
  % final list.  This presents us with a dilemma.  Inside the
  % function we need to do some token list manipulations.  These
  % must not propagate upwards to the calling function.  One way
  % to avoid this is to have the function be within a group, but
  % that has two disadvantages: the simplest way leads to a lot of
  % nested groups, and if we want to store the result rather than
  % simply typeset it then the assignments have to be global.
  % So we choose an alternative way which is to ensure that any
  % temporary variables are used as soon as possible after
  % definition and never span a recursive call to the function.
  % This makes the function mildly inefficient in that we can't
  % store and reuse some calculations.
  %
  % How many terms do we need to permute?
  \int_set:Nn \l__perm_len_int {\tl_count:n {#2}}
  \int_compare:nTF {\l__perm_len_int <= 1}
  {
    % Only one, so nothing to do.
    % Add it to the stream with the separator in front.
    \l__perm_sep: #1#2
  }
  {
    % More than one, so need to do the permutations.
    % The method is based on the Knuth shuffle.
    % We need to generate all of the permutations.  We can do this
    % recursively by the following algorithm.  We cyclically permute
    % the token list.  For each cyclic permutation we freeze the first
    % term and then apply the permutation generation function to the
    % rest of the list.
    %
    % Thus if we start with abc we generate the cyclic permutations.
    % These are abc, bca, cab.
    % Then for each of these, we freeze the first term and apply the
    % function to the rest: so with abc we freeze the a and apply the
    % generation function to bc.  This will (by recursion) generate
    % bc and cb, whence appending the a again yields abc and acb.
    %
    % To avoid nesting loops, each iteration creates a token list of
    % what it would do and that list is then inserted into the stream.
    \tl_clear:N \l__perm_all_tl
    \tl_set:Nn \l_tmpb_tl {#2}
    % We "freeze" the first term, adding it to the current prefix.
    \tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl {#1}
    \tl_put_right:Nx \l_tmpa_tl {\tl_head:N \l_tmpb_tl}
    % Now we add the first call to the recursive function to the
    % token list for this iteration.
    % This consists of a call to the function with arguments
    % the new prefix and the new tail.  We pass in the values so
    % that we can now use our temporary variables again with aplomb.
    \tl_put_right:Nn \l__perm_all_tl {\generate_perms:nn}
    \tl_put_right:Nx \l__perm_all_tl {{\exp_not:V \l_tmpa_tl}}
    \tl_put_right:Nx \l__perm_all_tl {{\tl_tail:N \l_tmpb_tl}}
    % Now we repeat the above but applying a cyclic permutation
    % to the main token list first
    \prg_replicate:nn {\l__perm_len_int - 1}
    {
      % This applies a cyclic permutation to the token list.
      \tl_set:Nx \l_tmpb_tl {\tl_tail:N \l_tmpb_tl {\tl_head:N \l_tmpb_tl}}
      % Then we add the function call to the token list.
      \tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl {#1}
      \tl_put_right:Nx \l_tmpa_tl {\tl_head:N \l_tmpb_tl}
      \tl_put_right:Nn \l__perm_all_tl {\generate_perms:nn}
      \tl_put_right:Nx \l__perm_all_tl {{\exp_not:V \l_tmpa_tl}}
      \tl_put_right:Nx \l__perm_all_tl {{\tl_tail:N \l_tmpb_tl}}
    }
    % The token list now contains all the needed recursive calls
    % which we can now call. 
    \l__perm_all_tl
  }
}

\cs_generate_variant:Nn \generate_perms:nn {VV}

% The optional argument is the separator, the mandatory one is the
% token list to permute.
\DeclareDocumentCommand \permute { O{,~} m }
{
  % Set the separator
  \set_separator:n {#1}
  % Generate the permutation list
  \generate_perms:nn {} {#2}
}

% This sets the separator.  The first separator typesets nothing but
% sets all the subsequent separators.  Normally the separator inserts
% the optional argument from the user but every 120 terms it inserts
% a \par token instead to avoid overload. 
\cs_new_nopar:Npn \set_separator:n #1
{
  \int_zero:N \l__perm_int
  \cs_set:Npn \l__perm_sep:
  {
    \cs_set:Npn \l__perm_sep:
    {
      \int_incr:N \l__perm_int
      \int_compare:nTF {\l__perm_int == 120}
      {
        \par
        \int_zero:N \l__perm_int
      }
      {
        #1
      }
    }
  }
}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\parskip=1em plus 1ex minus .5ex

\begin{document}
\noindent\raggedright\permute{abcdefghi}
\end{document}
```

[image: Permutations of abcde]

Comment: It is portable but the code looks too cryptic to me. :-)

Comment: output would look a bit nicer using `\noindent` and `\raggecright` locally for the paragraph.

Comment: @Bugbusters - you are asking too much. LaTeX is **not** a programming language, no matter how much it may pass for one sometimes.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Quite right.  I've updated it accordingly.

Comment: `\permute{abcdefghij}` seems to be an infinite loop ... :-) at least on my machine

Comment: @Herbert Yes, having seen your comment on Hendrik's answer then I tried testing and it works for `abcdefg` but not for `abcdefgh` on my machine (though I get "out of memory" rather than an infinite loop).  This is one of those things where I would favour the lualatex answer myself.  However, I viewed it as a challenge to implement in L3 to see how difficult it would be and to learn more about programming in L3.

Comment: I can squeeze one more letter by removing the assignment to the token list and simply inserting the tokens directly into the stream.  But it still complains at `abcdefghi`.

Comment: Well, with 9 letters, you are building a paragraph with `9!*11` characters (including spaces), which is around 4 millions.  A typical TeX has about 3 megabytes of memory, so fails.  It would be better to split the paragraph every now and then.

Comment: @BrunoLeFloch Ah, good point.  With code that avoids stacking up the recursion, then using `\par` as the separator I can get further (currently running `abcdefghij`, produced 13388 pages so far but a worrying sound is coming from my laptop!).

Comment: @BrunoLeFloch: I want only understand what happens. After 15 minutes I didn't get a memory problem only the infinte loop. A memory problem should appear after seconds.

Comment: New revision avoids nested loops and adds a few `\par`s now and again.  I've tried `abcdefghij` and it works.  Will now attempt `abcdefghijk` to see if my laptop survives.

Comment: @Herbert Did you get an infinite loop for smaller inputs?  Memory problems could appear in convoluted ways, and could perhaps crop up after a few seconds.  Another possibility is that you have an outdated version of the `l3kernel` bundle.

Comment: @BrunoLeFloch: No, it works fine for smaller inputs. I was only interested because infinit loops are very very rare in TeX. However, forget it and go on with your work :-)

Comment: @AndrewStacey You can gain a lot of speed by computing the first few "values", in particular, with a function such as `\def\permfive[#1]#2#3#4#5#6{#1#2#3#4#5#6, #1#2#3#4#6#5, ..., #1#6#5#4#3#2\par}`.  Then one only needs to list all choices of N-5 elements among the N we want to permute, feed it to `\permfive` as `#1`, and TeX will expand 120 terms of the list at once (and the `\par` that you work hard to insert.  Of course, this function should not be hard-coded with all 120 permutations, but built within the code.

Comment: @Herbert: You should try with one less letter, and see if it takes a reasonable time.  Then multiply the time it took by 10 (or a bit more) to have an estimate of how long the code will take for one more letter.  I've launched my own (rather faster) code with 11 letters, and it has been churning out pages for the last 15 minutes.

Comment: I got to 130,000 pages from `abcdefghijk` before my laptop ran out of battery.  Will try again tomorrow.

Comment: @Andrew: For 11 items, my code (with some `\par` added) needs about 4 minutes on my computer `:-)`

Comment: @HendrikVogt Confirmed: your code is much faster than mine.  Yours took about 8 minutes on my computer for 11 items whereas mine took over an hour.

Comment: @Andrew: Thanks for the comparison! Did you add a `\par` after _every_ permutation? It becomes about 15% faster if you add a `\par` after every _other_ permutation as I now propose in my answer, probably since the number of pages is cut in half. Of course it would be best if the algorithm would be able add a `\par` near the natural end of the line.

Comment: @HendrikVogt I did my best to make the two sets of code produce the same output and ran them a few times under different conditions.  For example, I added separator bit to your code from mine (which inserts a `\par` after every 120 permutations).  I suspect that there's a fair amount of overhead in using L3 which I'm not going to be able to get rid of, but my current goal for programmatic questions is to do them in L3 to try to learn that a bit better.

Comment: @Andrew: Thanks for the explanation! I have to admit that I didn't even have a look at how you insert the `\par` in your code ...

Answer (score 46):

Use the right tool for the job:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{python}

\begin{document}
\begin{python}
import itertools
for p in itertools.permutations("suvat"): print ''.join(p)
\end{python}
\end{document}
```

Run it with `pdflatex -shell-escape`.

Comment: cannot find `latex2.py.out`

Comment: @Bugbusters Did you run it with `pdflatex -shell-escape latex2.tex`? Oh, and of course you need `python` to be installed.

Comment: Yes. This code is very readable but uncompilable. :-)

Comment: You get this error when you do not enable `-shell-escape`. Normally, you should get a file `latex2.py` containing the code, `latex2.py.out` containing the output, and `latex2.py.err` containing errors from `python`.

Comment: Small note: calling `list` is not needed: `for p in itertools.permutations("suvat"): print ''.join(p)`

Comment: This could also be done with `pythontex`, if the calculations were ever slow enough that caching would be useful.

Answer (score 29):

The `\permute` macro is plain TeX, so it's very portable. Why don't you want it cryptic? It does the job, cryptically!

```
% New simplified code -- less cryptic than before :-)
\documentclass{article}
\def\recurse#1#2#3#4\endmarker{%
  \dopermute{#1#3}#2#4\endmarker
  \ifx\relax#4\relax\else % add a \par before \else if there are more than 8 items
    \recurse{#1}{#2#3}#4\endmarker
  \fi}
\def\dopermute#1#2#3\endmarker{%
  \ifx\relax#3\relax
    #1#2,
  \else
    \dopermute{#1#2}#3\endmarker
    \recurse{#1}{#2}#3\endmarker
  \fi}
\newcommand*\permute[1]{\dopermute{}#1\endmarker}
\begin{document}
\noindent\raggedright
\permute{12345}
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Note that `\permute` is picky and wants to be fed *single tokens*, so `\permute{12{34}}` won't work, but `\newcommand*\tf{34}\permute{12\tf}` will. (Would you really want to permute such a thing?)

Comment: that's nice, but will run into memory problems for 9 and more items.

Comment: @Herbert: Ah, right - I only tested up to 8, which already gave me 123 pages. For 9 items it would be more than a thousand pages!

Comment: @Herbert: You get `TeX capacity exceeded` only because the paragraph becomes too large. If you use `\par`s, then it nicely works with 11 items, too.

Comment: yes, that's true. Andrew already suggested it.

Comment: Just found a couple of edge cases: try permuting `ab{cd}` with yours and with mine; and try permuting `ab\relax cd` with yours!

Comment: @Andrew: As it should be, the algorithm `\relax`es if you ask it to do so `:-)` As for the `{cd}`: Yes, my version only works for single tokens. So `\newcommand*\tf{34}\permute{ab\tf}` works!

Answer (score 22):

run with `lualatex`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luacode}
\begin{luacode*}
local function perm_generate(a, n)
  if n == 0 then
    coroutine.yield(a)
  else
    for i=1,n do          
      a[n], a[i] = a[i], a[n]  -- put i-th element as the last one
      -- generate all permutations of the other elements
      perm_generate(a, n - 1)
      a[n], a[i] = a[i], a[n]  -- restore i-th element
    end
  end
end
function permutation(a)
  local n = #a
  return coroutine.wrap(function () perm_generate(a, n) end)
end
function print_result (a)
  for i,v in ipairs(a) do tex.print(v .. " ") end
  tex.print(" ")
end
\end{luacode*}

\def\printPermutations#1{\directlua{%
  itable = {#1};
  for p in permutation(itable) do print_result(p) end }}

\begin{document}
\printPermutations{"a","b","c","d","e"}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It is readable but less portable. :-)

Comment: @Bugbusters In contrast to the python solution it does not rely on external programs. IMO it's more portable, but I agree, it relies on a LuaTeX engine, though.

Answer (score 13):

A simple `LaTeX` code, restricted to 5 characters only:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\def\defPerm|#1#2#3#4#5|{\lccode`\1`#1\lccode`\2`#2\lccode`\3`#3\lccode`\4`#4\lccode`\5`#5}
\def\typePerm#1#2#3#4#5{\char\the\lccode`#1\char\the\lccode`#2\char\the\lccode`#3\char\the\lccode`#4\char\the\lccode`#5}%
\def\permuteV#1{{\defPerm|#1|\def\tmp{\foreach\next in {%
12345,12354,12435,12453,12534,12543,13245,13254,13425,13452,13524,13542,
14235,14253,14325,14352,14523,14532,15234,15243,15324,15342,15423,15432,
21345,21354,21435,21453,21534,21543,23145,23154,23415,23451,23514,23541,
24135,24153,24315,24351,24513,24531,25134,25143,25314,25341,25413,25431,
31245,31254,31425,31452,31524,31542,32145,32154,32415,32451,32514,32541,
34125,34152,34215,34251,34512,34521,35124,35142,35214,35241,35412,35421,
41235,41253,41325,41352,41523,41532,42135,42153,42315,42351,42513,42531,
43125,43152,43215,43251,43512,43521,45123,45132,45213,45231,45312,45321,
51234,51243,51324,51342,51423,51432,52134,52143,52314,52341,52413,52431,
53124,53142,53214,53241,53412,53421,54123,54132,54213,54231,54312,54321}
{\expandafter\typePerm\next{} }}\tmp}}%
%
\begin{document}

\noindent\permuteV{suvat}

\noindent\permuteV{LaTeX}

\noindent\texttt{\permuteV{@1234}}

\end{document}
```

[image]